# how i can get my info through the random key by push

Tags: java, android, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have JsonString by receive DataSnapShot:

```
myRef.child("user").orderByChild("u_email").equalTo(name).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            String c = dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();
                            Log.w(Login.TAG, "Data: "+ c);
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                        }
                    });
```

in normal if i know the key (-L3Mh7kKl04GSrndbrVD) ill code:

```
JSONObject a = new JSONObject(c);
JSONObject jsonUser = a.getJSONObject("-L3Mh7kKl04GSrndbrVD");
```

But i dont have that key, How i can get that value (name, pass, img, ...) with code, im newbie. Thanks all alot

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
  DatabaseReference references=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("user");
references.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot data: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
           String name=data.child("name").getValue().toString();
           String password=data.child("pass").getValue().toString();
           String img=data.child("img").getValue().toString();

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

Here the reference is the user node, then using the for loop it will iterate inside every push id to give you the values (name,img,pass,...).

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
    myRef.child("user").orderByChild("u_email").equalTo(name).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        String c = dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();
                        Log.w(Login.TAG, "Data: "+ c);
                        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                         String u_img = ds.child("u_img").getValue(String.class);
                         String u_pass = ds.child("u_pass").getValue(String.class);
                         String u_address = ds.child("u_address").getValue(String.class);
        Log.d("TAG",u_img + " / " + u_pass + " / " + u_address);
        }
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    }
                });
```